# Updating model method during queryset list

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model with a score than is updated from a model method.

```
class Member(models.Model):

  score = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)

  def update_score(self):
       self.score = new_score()
       self.save()
```

Next I query all members and order by score:

```
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
     super(MemberListView, self).filter_queryset(queryset) \
            .filter() \
            .order_by('score')
```

My problem is I need a way to update all scores for each model returned (`update_score`) **before** I order them above. I could do this in Python, but I'm scared this will become slow and is a bad idea. What are my options and how could this be done? I'm using `postgis`

Or I don;t have to save the value, just order by it, can you run a function and order by the results of that function for each instance returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can you run a function and order by the results of that function for each instance returned?"

Yes you can :).

```
def score_func(model):
    score = do_something_to_get_score(model)
    return score

results = sorted(list_of_models, score_func)
```

Comment: Would this work: ``sorted(queryset, key=lambda t: t.update_intrest())``?

Comment: Sure, assuming `t.update_intrest()` returns the value you want to sort by. Just to mention it, you could also do `sorted(queryset, key=ClassOf_t.update_intrest)`.